# React native compile error on resolving module

Tags: react-native

I can't compile my project because of this error.

> Unable to resolve module `@react-navigation/core` from
>   `node_modules\@react-navigation\native\src\createAppContainer.js`:

When I run I encounter with this problem. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes such error occurs as the package-json.lock file which locks the version.

So do 1 thing remove the version of @react-navigation and all related dependencies from your package.json and after that do following once again

```
npm install @react-navigation/native --save

npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view --save
```

Must help!

Answer (score 2):

This error means that either you haven't installed the `react-navigation` module or that you have installed the module but didn't re-built your project using `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`.

Following these steps should solve your issue:

- Install `react-navigation` module.
- Re-build your project.
- Restart the packager by stopping the current packager and then
  starting the packager again
- `with react-native start.`